# Mandatory boost::spirit::qi::attr(0) in rule is beeing skipped

Tags: c++, boost, attr, boost-spirit-qi

I am struggeling with the implementation of a rule where all elements are part of a list of sorts. The types of elements can not be mixed.

This is valid: `1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/` and should be parsed with a mandatory zero like `1/1/0 2/2/0 3/3/0`

The example below includes a rule where I think an attribute is created. It works for the `int_/0/int_` variation but not for the `int_/int_/0` version.
In fact the attribute zero seems to be skipped entirely and the next int_ (the number 2) is used instead.

Here is some commented output:

[image]

This is a longer example that includes all tests and rules used:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <list>
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

typedef struct { int a; int b; int c; } int_triplet;
typedef struct std::vector<int_triplet> int_triplet_vector;
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(int_triplet, a, b, c)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::string::iterator Iterator;

typedef qi::rule<Iterator> skipper_rule;
typedef qi::rule<Iterator> line_rule;
typedef qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), skipper_rule> string_rule;
typedef qi::rule<Iterator, int_triplet(), skipper_rule> int_triplet_rule;
typedef qi::rule<Iterator, int_triplet_vector(), skipper_rule> int_triplet_vector_rule;

line_rule endofline = qi::lit("\r\n") | qi::lit("\n\r") | qi::lit('\n');
skipper_rule skip = qi::lit(' ') | qi::lit('\t') | qi::lit('\f') | qi::lit('\v') | (qi::lit('\\') >> endofline);

int_triplet_rule faceIndex_v_0_vn = qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::attr((int)0) >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::int_;
//int_triplet_rule faceIndex_v_vt__0 = qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::attr(0);
int_triplet_rule faceIndex_v_vt_0 = qi::lexeme[qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> ((!qi::int_) | qi::attr((int)0))];
int_triplet_rule faceIndex_v_vt_vn = qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::int_ >> qi::lit('/') >> qi::int_;
int_triplet_vector_rule f = 'f' >> (+faceIndex_v_vt_vn | +faceIndex_v_0_vn | +faceIndex_v_vt_0) >> endofline;
//int_triplet_vector_rule f = 'f' >> (+faceIndex_v_vt_vn | +faceIndex_v__0_vn | +faceIndex_v_vt__0 ) >> endofline;
//int_triplet_vector_rule f = 'f' >> *( faceIndex_v__0_vn | faceIndex_v_vt__0 | faceIndex_v_vt_vn ) >> endofline;

std::string ReplaceTRNVF(std::string str)
{
    std::string strmod = str;
    std::list<std::string> rs = { "\\t", "\\r", "\\n", "\\v", "\\f" };
    for(auto r : rs)
        strmod = std::regex_replace(strmod, std::regex(r), r);
    return strmod;
}

void CHECK(std::string::iterator & it, std::string::iterator & end)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(it == end, ReplaceTRNVF((std::string)"Remaining:'" + std::string(it, end) + "'"));
}

void CHECK(int_triplet &expected, int_triplet &actual)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected.a, actual.a);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected.b, actual.b);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected.c, actual.c);
}

void CHECK(int_triplet_vector &expected, int_triplet_vector &actual)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected.size(), actual.size());
    for (size_t n = 0; n < expected.size() && n < actual.size(); ++n)
        CHECK(expected[n], actual[n]);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Rules_FaceIndex_Pass)
{
    std::map<std::string, int_triplet_vector> data;
    data["f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4\r\n"] = int_triplet_vector{ { 1, 1, 1 },{ 2, 2, 2 },{ 3, 3, 3 },{ 4, 4, 4 } };
    data["f 1//1 2//2 3//3 4//4\r\n"] = int_triplet_vector{ { 1, 0, 1 },{ 2, 0, 2 },{ 3, 0, 3 },{ 4, 0, 4 } };
    data["f 1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/ 4/4/\r\n"] = int_triplet_vector{ { 1, 1, 0 },{ 2, 2, 0 },{ 3, 3, 0 },{ 4, 4, 0 } };

    for (auto kvp : data)
    {
        int_triplet_vector result;
        std::string test = kvp.first;
        auto it = test.begin();
        std::cout << ReplaceTRNVF("Test: " + test) << std::endl;
        BOOST_CHECK(true == qi::phrase_parse(it, test.end(), f, skip, result));
        CHECK(it, test.end());
        CHECK(kvp.second, result);
    }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Rules_FaceIndex_Fail)
{
    std::list<std::string> data = 
    { 
        "f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3//3 4//4\r\n", 
        "f 1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/ 4/4/4\r\n",
    };

    for (auto t : data)
    {
        int_triplet_vector result;
        std::string test = t;
        std::cout << ReplaceTRNVF("Test: " + test) << std::endl;
        auto it = test.begin();
        BOOST_CHECK(false == qi::phrase_parse(it, test.end(), f, skip, result));
    }
}
```

How can I make the attribute unsinkable so that it is always used to fill the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I spent way too much time cleaning up some of the code.

The problem likely resided in `!int_ | attr(0)`. Because, firstly says "either you don't see another int, ***or*** you use the implied `0`". That's exactly what you didn't want to say, I think.

> Note: _postive lookahead would be `&int_` - but even then that would not be what you wanted, because then you would want to actually parse it, and `&int_ >> int_` is very much equivalent to `int_`.

Also, in general I didn't see the reason to complicate the tiplet rules with skippers (there are no spaces in any of the sample triplets; also, allowing them does make the grammar ambiguous, because there would be no way to tell whether a given integer was the trailing number from the previous triplet, or the leading one from the next.)

Removing the skipper from the actual triplet, removes the pain:

```
using namespace qi;

skip_    = char_(" \t\f\v") | '\\' >> eol;

t1       = int_ >> '/' >> int_    >> '/' >> int_;
t2       = int_ >> '/' >> attr(0) >> '/' >> int_;
t3       = int_ >> '/' >> int_    >> '/' >> attr(0);
triplets = +t1 | +t2 | +t3;

f        = 'f' >> triplets >> eol;
start    = skip(copy(skip_)) [ f ];
```

Here's the end result of my transfrobnications:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/541a6d63f33929a8)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
//#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <list>
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, vector<T> const& v) {
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, " "));
        return os;
    }
}

struct int_triplet {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    bool operator==(int_triplet const& other) const {
        return (a == other.a) 
            && (b == other.b)
            && (c == other.c);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, int_triplet const& t) {
        return os << t.a << '/' << t.b << '/' << t.c;
    }
};

typedef std::vector<int_triplet> int_triplet_vector;

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(int_triplet, a, b, c)

namespace parsing {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename Iterator> 
        struct grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, int_triplet_vector()> {
            grammar() : grammar::base_type(start) {
                using namespace qi;

                skip_    = char_(" \t\f\v") | '\\' >> eol;

                t1       = int_ >> '/' >> int_    >> '/' >> int_;
                t2       = int_ >> '/' >> attr(0) >> '/' >> int_;
                t3       = int_ >> '/' >> int_    >> '/' >> attr(0);
                triplets = +t1 | +t2 | +t3;

                f        = 'f' >> triplets >> eol;
                start    = skip(copy(skip_)) [ f ];

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((skip_)(t1)(t2)(t3)(triplets)(f)(start))
            }

          private:
            qi::rule<Iterator, int_triplet_vector()> start;

            typedef qi::rule<Iterator> Skipper;

            Skipper skip_;
            qi::rule<Iterator, int_triplet()> t1, t2, t3;
            qi::rule<Iterator, int_triplet_vector(), Skipper> f, triplets;
        };

    static grammar<std::string::const_iterator> const f {};
}

std::string escape(std::string str) {
    std::list<std::string> rs = { "\\t", "\\r", "\\n", "\\v", "\\f" };
    for (auto r : rs)
        str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex(r), r);
    return str;
}

void CHECK(std::string::const_iterator it, std::string::const_iterator end) {
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(it == end, escape((std::string) "Remaining:'" + std::string(it, end) + "'"));
}

void CHECK(int_triplet const&expected, int_triplet const&actual) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected, actual);
}

void CHECK(int_triplet_vector const&expected, int_triplet_vector const&actual) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected.size(), actual.size());
    for (size_t n = 0; n < expected.size() && n < actual.size(); ++n)
        CHECK(expected[n], actual[n]);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Rules_FaceIndex_Pass) {
    std::map<std::string, int_triplet_vector> const data {
        {"f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4\r\n", int_triplet_vector{ { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3 }, { 4, 4, 4 } }},
        {"f 1//1 2//2 3//3 4//4\r\n"    , int_triplet_vector{ { 1, 0, 1 }, { 2, 0, 2 }, { 3, 0, 3 }, { 4, 0, 4 } }},
        {"f 1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/ 4/4/\r\n"    , int_triplet_vector{ { 1, 1, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0 }, { 3, 3, 0 }, { 4, 4, 0 } }},
    };

    for (auto const& kvp : data) {

        auto& test = kvp.first;
        std::cout << "Test: " << escape(test) << std::endl;

        auto it = test.begin();
        int_triplet_vector result;
        BOOST_CHECK(true == parse(it, test.end(), parsing::f, result));

        CHECK(it, test.cend());
        CHECK(kvp.second, result);
    }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Rules_FaceIndex_Fail) {
    std::list<std::string> const data = {
        "f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3//3 4//4\r\n", "f 1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/ 4/4/4\r\n",
    };

    for (std::string const& t : data) {
        int_triplet_vector result;
        std::cout << "Test: " << escape(t) << std::endl;

        auto it = t.begin();

        BOOST_CHECK(false == parse(it, t.end(), parsing::f, result));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Running 2 test cases...
Test: f 1//1 2//2 3//3 4//4\r\n
Test: f 1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/ 4/4/\r\n
Test: f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4\r\n
Test: f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3//3 4//4\r\n
Test: f 1/1/ 2/2/ 3/3/ 4/4/4\r\n

*** No errors detected
```

(That's with debug information disabled, of course)

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort of cleaning. I will see what lessons I can find in there and refactor my codebase.